# RESTful post in Oracle Service Bus

Tags: rest, oracle11g, restful-url, osb, oracle-service-bus

Does anyone know how to create a proxy service that will handle this sort of thing?

What I'm looking for is a path parameter and a post body being formatted similar to this:

POST www.myurl.com/{123}

Post body:
myId=1&myOtherId=2

I am currently passing in an XML document and I'm doing an insert on the http:relative-URI element in the transport. This seems to work.

I am also currently doing an insert on the http:query-parameters for my post body name/value pairs.

I am inserting these on the outbound variable. When I debug, both are showing up and I'm contacting the REST service. I am getting a 400 -- Bad Request error. This happens when the post body is not configured correctly.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just Posting an XML, then while creating Proxy Service, Select Service Type as Any XML.